# In what ways does/do soils differ?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Today I found the following question in a question paper

**In what ways does soils differ?**

My understanding is that the **subject** here in this sentence is **soils**, which is plural.
If the subject is plural how can we use does in that question?
Isn't that question wrong?

I believe that the correct question is : **In what ways do soils differ?**

Which one is correct?

-I am asking this question because it appeared in an exam conducted by a government agency and I am sure that questions were made by experts.-=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct and the original sentence is wrong.  **Soils** is plural, so we would conjugate the verbs accordingly, whether it's the main verb or an auxiliary: "Soils **differ** / In what ways **do** soils differ".

> I am asking this question because it appeared in an exam conducted by a government agency and I am sure that questions were made by experts.

I hate to tell you this, but governments and experts make mistakes all the time.